# FirstOrDefault call in entity framework is cached but database is changed

Tags: sql, entity-framework, caching, entity-framework-5

I have a strange issue, which I haven't experienced before. I use Entity Framework to retrieve my records.

I have the following call:

```
 var dbOrganisation = repository.DbOrganisation.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);
```

I expect no caching of this call. So when I make this call, I expect it to query the database and retrieve the latest `DbOrganisation` object. But that is not what happens.

I call this method relatively two times relatively short time after eachother (~5-10 seconds). But in this period, a decimal value in this table, can be changed by some third party.

However, even though the value changes, the `FirstOrDefault` call retrieves the not updated version.

**Example situation**:

1. I make the `FirstOrDefault` call, and see the decimal value of the field `Credits`, is 50
2. A third party changes the `Credits` to 45
3. I make the `FirstOrDefault` call 10 seconds, later, but the `DbOrganisation` still have 50 in Credits

What am i doing wrong? I thought the `FirstOrDefault` call was not cached by default?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You doing everything correct, that's just how EF works.

You can use `.AsNoTracking()` for you purposes:

```
var dbOrganisation = repository.DbOrganisation.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);
```

[DbExtensions.AsNoTracking Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679352%28v=vs.103%29.aspx): Returns a new query where the entities returned will not be cached in the DbContext or ObjectContext.